# Facebook bot with Php (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (messages) on node type (Page)

Tags: facebook, bots

I'm trying to make Facebook bot with PHP, but when i try to open
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me/messages?access_token=MY-ACCESS-TOKEN

I got this error message.

> {
>   "error": {
>         "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (messages) on node type (Page)",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 100,
>         "fbtrace_id": "FsRWv82pTHO"
>   } }

Also when i open my code i got this error.

> Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in
>
> ```
> /storage/ssd3/943/6474943/public_html/index.php on line 11
> ```

Answer (score 5):

You are using a page access token and trying to get `/{your-page}/messages`, that seems to be a valid endpoint only for POST requests: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/.

What you are looking for instead is `/me/conversations`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations/.

Comment: Just in case anyone else arrives at this page for a different reason...I got this when I was mistakenly sending a GET rather than POST request, so seems to be a rather unhelpful and generic error message!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
{page-id}/conversations/messages?access_token=page-token
```