# (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (messages) on node type (User)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

When I try to get the Messages sent to my Facebook Page, which is linked to Messenger chatbot I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (messages) on node type (User)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "A5W_BFDXx9GgriZb697u5zv
"
  }
}
```

Here is also an image of the output:

[image]

The Access Token is valid for sure. I have tested below:

[image]

Note that the Page is neither Business Verified, not Individual verified. I don't know if this plays a role. However, even though the Page Access Token seems correct, I can't run the GET query.

Update - Use Page Access Token

[image]

Comment: You are using a user token, not a page token.

Comment: @CBroe Ok that was a good point I missed. Now I generated a new token and I get the same error but for the page ```"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (messages) on node type (Page)"```

Comment: @CBroe can it be the case that messages is only valid for POST requests?...While me/conversations is valid for GET requests? Please review this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54234305/facebook-bot-with-php-100-tried-accessing-nonexisting-field-messages-on-nod

Comment: A `messages` edge is not even mentioned in the documentation for the Page object any more. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations/ is the way to read page conversations.

Comment: @CBroe ok probably the article from which I took the code is depricated. Can you validate it?..This is the article https://medium.com/codebagng/building-a-gif-messenger-bot-with-flask-fcdca58e581c

Comment: @CBroe Basically I want to send GIF images to messenger bot using this command ```r = requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
                      params=params, headers=headers, data=data)```...Shall I change this to ```r = requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/me/conversations",
                      params=params, headers=headers, data=data)```?

Comment: No, for sending, that should be the correct endpoint (although probably not with such a massively outdated API version as v2.6.) But you are dealing with the Messenger API here then, so you should first and foremost read the documentation for that - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/

Comment: @CBroe So the ```r= requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/me/messages",                       params=params, headers=headers, data=data)``` should be the correct endpoint...I use 7.0 instead of 2.6...Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciate it. Can you post it as answer so I can upvote you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ doesn’t mention the `messages` edge any more, but how to use it to send messages, is explained as part of the Messenger API documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/

So, `/me/messages` is the correct endpoint for that, to be used with a page access token. And since sending messages is a “creating” action, it needs to be a POST request.

---

Be aware though that you can not just arbitrarily send messages whenever and to whomever you want - usually, the user needs to make contact with your page first, so that your bot can then respond to that. The details of the different types of messaging, and their restrictions, are explained unter https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages